# Piecemeal processing of a matrix - CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda

OK, so lets say I have an ( N x N ) matrix that I would like to process. This matrix is quite large for my computer, and if I try to send it to the device all at once I get a 'out of memory error.'

So is there a way to send sections of the matrix to the device? One way I can see to do it is copy portions of the matrix on the host, and then send these manageable copied portions from the host to the device, and then put them back together at the end.

Here is something I have tried, but the cudaMemcpy in the for loop returns error code 11, 'invalid argument.'

```
int h_N = 10000;
size_t h_size_m = h_N*sizeof(float);
h_A  = (float*)malloc(h_size_m*h_size_m);

int d_N = 2500;
size_t d_size_m = d_N*sizeof(float);

InitializeMatrices(h_N);

int i;
int iterations = (h_N*h_N)/(d_N*d_N);

for( i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ) 
{
    float* h_array_ref = h_A+(i*d_N*d_N);
    cudasafe( cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_array_ref, d_size_m*d_size_m, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice), "cudaMemcpy");
    cudasafe( cudaFree(d_A), "cudaFree(d_A)" );
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish with the above code is this: instead of send the entire matrix to the device, I simply send a pointer to a place within that matrix and reserve enough space on the device to do the work, and then with the next iteration of the loop move the pointer forward within the matrix, etc. etc.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do tiled processing of matrices in the manner you describe. As for your current issue, I do not see a cudaMalloc() for the matrix tile in your code. Note that due to the 2D  layout of a matrix, each tile will need to be copied with cudaMemcpy2D() as the rows (or columns, depending on your storage convention) of each tile are not contiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only *can* you do this (assuming your problem is easily decomposed this way into sub-arrays), it can be a very useful thing to do for performance; once you get the basic approach you've described working, you can start using [asynchronous memory copies](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf) and double-buffering to overlap some of the memory transfer time with the time spent computing what is already on-card.

But first one gets the simple thing working.  Below is a 1d example (multiplying a vector by a scalar and adding another scalar) but using a linearized 2d array would be the same; the key part is

```
CHK_CUDA( cudaMalloc(&xd, batchsize*sizeof(float)) );
CHK_CUDA( cudaMalloc(&yd, batchsize*sizeof(float)) );
tick(&gputimer);

int nbatches = 0;
for (int nstart=0; nstart < n; nstart+=batchsize) {

    int size=batchsize;
    if ((nstart + batchsize) > n) size = n - nstart;

    CHK_CUDA( cudaMemcpy(xd, &(x[nstart]), size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    blocksize = (size+nblocks-1)/nblocks;
    cuda_saxpb<<<nblocks, blocksize>>>(xd, a, b, yd, size);

    CHK_CUDA( cudaMemcpy(&(ycuda[nstart]), yd, size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    nbatches++;
}
gputime = tock(&gputimer);

CHK_CUDA( cudaFree(xd) );
CHK_CUDA( cudaFree(yd) );
```

You allocate the buffers at the start, and then loop through until you're done, each time doing the copy, starting the kernel, and then copying back.   You free at the end.

The full code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define CHK_CUDA(e) {if (e != cudaSuccess) {fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(e)); exit(-1);}}

__global__ void cuda_saxpb(const float *xd, const float a, const float b,
                           float *yd, const int n) {

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (i<n) {
        yd[i] = a*xd[i]+b;
    }
    return;
}

void cpu_saxpb(const float *x, float a, float b, float *y, int n) {

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        y[i] = a*x[i]+b;
    }
    return;
}

int get_options(int argc, char **argv, int *n, int *s, int *nb, float *a, float *b);
void tick(struct timeval *timer);
double tock(struct timeval *timer);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n=1000;
    int nblocks=10;
    int batchsize=100;
    float a = 5.;
    float b = -1.;
    int err;
    float *x, *y, *ycuda;
    float *xd, *yd;
    double abserr;
    int blocksize;
    int i;
    struct timeval cputimer;
    struct timeval gputimer;
    double cputime, gputime;

    err = get_options(argc, argv, &n, &batchsize, &nblocks, &a, &b);
    if (batchsize > n) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Resetting batchsize to size of vector, %d\n", n);
        batchsize = n;
    }
    if (err) return 0;

    x = (float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    if (!x) return 1;

    y = (float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    if (!y) {free(x); return 1;}

    ycuda = (float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    if (!ycuda) {free(y); free(x); return 1;}

    /* run CPU code */

    tick(&cputimer);
    cpu_saxpb(x, a, b, y, n);
    cputime = tock(&cputimer);

    /* run GPU code */

    /* only have to allocate once */
    CHK_CUDA( cudaMalloc(&xd, batchsize*sizeof(float)) );
    CHK_CUDA( cudaMalloc(&yd, batchsize*sizeof(float)) );
    tick(&gputimer);

    int nbatches = 0;
    for (int nstart=0; nstart < n; nstart+=batchsize) {

        int size=batchsize;
        if ((nstart + batchsize) > n) size = n - nstart;

        CHK_CUDA( cudaMemcpy(xd, &(x[nstart]), size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

        blocksize = (size+nblocks-1)/nblocks;
        cuda_saxpb<<<nblocks, blocksize>>>(xd, a, b, yd, size);

        CHK_CUDA( cudaMemcpy(&(ycuda[nstart]), yd, size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

        nbatches++;
    }
    gputime = tock(&gputimer);

    CHK_CUDA( cudaFree(xd) );
    CHK_CUDA( cudaFree(yd) );

    abserr = 0.;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        abserr += fabs(ycuda[i] - y[i]);
    }

    printf("Y = a*X + b, problemsize = %d\n", n);
    printf("CPU time = %lg millisec.\n", cputime*1000.);
    printf("GPU time = %lg millisec (done with %d batches of %d).\n",
                  gputime*1000., nbatches, batchsize);
    printf("CUDA and CPU results differ by %lf\n", abserr);

    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(ycuda);
    return 0;
}


int get_options(int argc, char **argv, int *n, int *s, int *nb, float *a, float *b) {

  const struct option long_options[] = {
    {"nvals"     , required_argument, 0, 'n'},
    {"nblocks"   , required_argument, 0, 'B'},
    {"batchsize" , required_argument, 0, 's'},
    {"a", required_argument, 0, 'a'},
    {"b", required_argument, 0, 'b'},
    {"help",      no_argument, 0, 'h'},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}};

  char c;
  int option_index;
  int tempint;

  while (1) {
    c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "n:B:a:b:s:h", long_options, &option_index);
    if (c == -1) break;

    switch(c) {
      case 'n': tempint = atoi(optarg);
          if (tempint < 1 || tempint > 500000) {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s: Cannot use number of points %s;\n  Using %d\n", argv[0], optarg, *n);
          } else {
            *n = tempint;
          }
          break;

      case 's': tempint = atoi(optarg);
          if (tempint < 1 || tempint > 50000) {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s: Cannot use number of points %s;\n  Using %d\n", argv[0], optarg, *s);
          } else {
            *s = tempint;
          }
          break;

      case 'B': tempint = atoi(optarg);
          if (tempint < 1 || tempint > 1000 || tempint > *n) {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s: Cannot use number of blocks %s;\n  Using %d\n", argv[0], optarg, *nb);
          } else {
            *nb = tempint;
          }
          break;

      case 'a': *a = atof(optarg);
          break;

      case 'b': *b = atof(optarg);
          break;

      case 'h':
          puts("Calculates y[i] = a*x[i] + b on the GPU.");
          puts("Options: ");
          puts("    --nvals=N      (-n N): Set the number of values in y,x.");
          puts("    --batchsize=N  (-s N): Set the number of values to transfer at a time.");
          puts("    --nblocks=N    (-B N): Set the number of blocks used.");
          puts("    --a=X          (-a X): Set the parameter a.");
          puts("    --b=X          (-b X): Set the parameter b.");
          puts("    --niters=N     (-I X): Set number of iterations to calculate.");
          puts("");
          return +1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void tick(struct timeval *timer) {
    gettimeofday(timer, NULL);
}

double tock(struct timeval *timer) {
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    return (now.tv_usec-timer->tv_usec)/1.0e6 + (now.tv_sec - timer->tv_sec);
}
```

Running this one gets:

```
$  ./batched-saxpb --nvals=10240 --batchsize=10240 --nblocks=20
Y = a*X + b, problemsize = 10240
CPU time = 0.072 millisec.
GPU time = 0.117 millisec (done with 1 batches of 10240).
CUDA and CPU results differ by 0.000000

$ ./batched-saxpb --nvals=10240 --batchsize=5120 --nblocks=20
Y = a*X + b, problemsize = 10240
CPU time = 0.066 millisec.
GPU time = 0.133 millisec (done with 2 batches of 5120).
CUDA and CPU results differ by 0.000000

$ ./batched-saxpb --nvals=10240 --batchsize=2560 --nblocks=20
Y = a*X + b, problemsize = 10240
CPU time = 0.067 millisec.
GPU time = 0.167 millisec (done with 4 batches of 2560).
CUDA and CPU results differ by 0.000000
```

The GPU time goes up in this case (we're doing more memory copies) but the answers stay the same.

**Edited:** The original version of this code had an option for running multiple iterations of the kernel for timing purposes, but that's unnecessarily confusing in this context so it's removed.

Comment: Note the slight edit for clarity of the code; just realized that iterating over the kernel launch is really confusing in this context.